# How to create a Pop up box on laravel

Tags: laravel, popup, messagebox, popupwindow

I want to create a popup box which will be load after website full loading. I want show some notice or advertisement to user by this pop up box which will be auto appear after web loading. So how do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is majorly a frontend task. So, Id do it in the following way:

- Use laravel to render the page i want to display the popup
- On the blade view of the page I will use html, css and javascript to structure, style and show the pop up when the page loads.

This link might provide you more information: https://websolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-add-bootstrap-modal-in-laravel?ref=morioh.com&utm_source=morioh.com